# SQL compare multiple numbers in one column within case statement

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto

I have the following table:

```
|n|Minutes|Pressure|
--------------------
|1|0.5    |2.8     |
|2|1      |3.2     |
|3|1.5    |3.3     |
```

and I need to check if the pressure at 1 minute > pressure at 0.5 minutes and that the pressure at 1.5 minutes > the pressure at 1 minute, returning 1 if true and 0 if false. This is accomplished in excel with the following formula:

```
=IF(AND(B11<B10,B12<B11),1,0)
```

And i want the following output

```
|n|Minutes|Pressure|dP|
-----------------------
|1|0.5    |2.8     |1 |
|2|1      |3.2     |1 |
|3|1.5    |3.3     |1 |
```

I am familiar enough with SQL to know to use a case statement with and for both criteria, but i need some guidance iterating the check across the entire table. Basically, dP in the first row checks the pressures in the 2nd and 3rd rows, then dP in the second row will check the pressures in the 3rd and 4th rows, and so on.

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.

Comment: The table above is what i want. The query needs to select the conditional check as dP. I'll edit it to make it more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want `lead()`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when lead(pressure, 1) over (order by n) < pressure and
                  lead(pressure, 2) over (order by n) < lead(pressure, 1) over (order by n)
             then 1 else 0
        end) as dp
from t;
```